# How to do Testing on JavaScript changes

Tags: javascript, testing, frontend

In an Assignment it was asked what is the first thing to do before testing changes done in JavaScript, after deploying an application. My answer was to clean the browser cache because the cached content may affect the new changes. I want to know whether it is a valid and a good answer or are there some things to do prior to that? Thank you

Comment: "cache", not "cash".

Comment: Looks like a trick question to me, you should definitely be writing unit / integration / e2e tests before deploying in production and testing manually.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think the question is: "I have already deployed a page, now I have made changes and want to test those before deploying the update and, if the update is OK, does the user have to do anything before running the new page"?

Answer (score 0):

A word of advice, not all users understand the principle of clearing the browser cache to obtain changes. I suggest you to increment you'r javascript file instead of taking into consideration that users will clear their cache.

But before deploying a modification, I advise you to do some tests. Several types of test exist, you can look for example at unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

What a vague question to be asked, however I personally think about how a *real* user would use the system when I test it.  Therefore, would I trust the user to clear the cache / cookies etc everytime they used the system? No.  I would expect to be able to either close the browser and open (or simply refresh the screen). As mentioned in another answer, 'cache busting' should be handled by the developer during the build process, for example by hashing the javascript bundle.

I used to get into a habit of opening dev tools all of the time and relying on the 'disable cache' toggle, however after a few times of getting caught out by real users seeing different behaviour that what i was seeing during development, I moved to ensure that the bundles weren't cached in both dev and prod.